# Merge all the csv file in one folder and add a new column to pandas dataframe with partial file name in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a folder inside have over 100 CSV files. They all have the same prefix name. 
    eg: 
    shcool.Math001.csv
    School.Math002.csv. 
    School.Physics001.csv. etc... They all contain the same number of columns.

```
How can I merge all the CSV files in one data frame in Python and add a new column with those files names but the prefix name "School." needs to be removed?

I found some code example online but did not sovle my problem:

path = r'C:\\Users\\me\\data\\'              
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*"))

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t') for f in all_files)
concatdf = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, haven't tested:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

path ='<folder path to CSVs>'
dfs = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    sample_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    sample_df['filename'] = ''.join(filename[7:])
    dfs.append(sample_df)


df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got error code: '"Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2."

Answer (score 0):

Add [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) in generator comprehension for add new column:

```
path = r'C:\\Users\\me\\data\\'              
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*"))

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t').assign(New=+os.path.basename(f[7:]).split('.')[0]) for f in all_files)
concatdf = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```